# Extract from Cache.db files on Mac OS X Leopard

Tags: java, caching, macos

I am a Windows user, and I delete temp internet files from IE by URL visited (because the Java app has an embedded web browser tied to a web server).

I read from another post that the Cache.db file stores responses from webservers when it is an app bundle (/users/username/library/caches/myappbundle/cache.db). Is it possible to extract files out of this db file and view them?

Windows spits out the file, no name change, and I could drag it out of the temp dir and double click if caching was allowed. I wanted to know if its possible on a Mac to retrieve files in a similar fashion (i know mac changes the name and extension but one could clear the cache, run the app, and guess the extension depending on the cached file size).

My app embeds Safari when run on a Mac, but the safari cache in "com.app.safari" does not grown as i run my app (the app bundle cache and/or java websatart cache do grow). Is it possible to retrieve the decrypted files from these DB files? If not, are they stored elsewhere in a tmp directory of some type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a definitive answer for you, but you might try using [FSEventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start) to view real-time filesystem changes. Then you'll know for sure where your caches are being stored.

Comment: This tool does help. Files keep going to "private/tmp/var/folders" and the rest of the path seems almost random. The files in the "-Tmp" dir at the end are really deleted as soon as they appear it seems. I can delete "cache.db" of course, but want to know implications if i do not. Thanks for this tip.